# Incorrect value while calculating difference in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to check if the value in `'diff'` column is greater than `0` if it is, then the value in `'worth'` should be `False` else it should be `True`

I am using the below code to compute and check but it always gives me `True`. Can anyone point here what is the mistake. I am attaching pic of output as well

```
last_row_index = len(df.index) - 1
previous_row_index = last_row_index - 1
last_fifty_rows = len(df.index) - 100
ema8 = ta.trend.ema_indicator(df['close'], 100)
df['ema'] = ema8
df['diff'] = 0
df['worth'] = False

for current in range(last_fifty_rows, len(df.index)):
    df['diff'][current]=df['ema'][current] - df['close'][current]
    if df['diff'][current] < 0:
     df['worth'][current]= 'True'
    elif df['diff'][current] > 0:
     df['worth'][current]= 'False'
```

The output is as follows

```
     timestamp                   open      high      low     close       volume  ...     upperband     lowerband     in_uptrend      ema      diff  worth
194 2021-06-16 01:05:00+05:30  40091.32  40151.71  40050.0  40127.34   450.503517  ...  40794.806429  39406.903571       False  40330.573417   203   True
195 2021-06-16 01:10:00+05:30  40127.33  40150.00  40060.0  40104.08   234.711677  ...  40784.525714  39425.474286       False  40326.088399   222   True
196 2021-06-16 01:15:00+05:30  40104.08  40137.21  39990.0  40039.18   424.682602  ...  40733.483571  39393.726429       False  40320.407044   281   True
197 2021-06-16 01:20:00+05:30  40036.80  40077.54  39768.0  39869.20  1010.464309  ...  40677.252857  39168.287143       False  40311.472251   442   True
198 2021-06-16 01:25:00+05:30  39869.20  39990.91  39869.2  39958.01   269.617684  ...  40552.777857  39307.332143       False  40304.472999   346   True
```

Comment: Can you give a sample of df before the for loop `df.head().to_dict()`?

Comment: @HenryEcker I have added the output image

Comment: No images please. Can you copy and paste the output?

Comment: @tomjn Thanks for answering. I have added output as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with subtraction + [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where) instead:

```
df['diff'] = df['ema'] - df['close']
df['worth'] = np.where(df['diff'].gt(0), False, True)
```

Or with [`Series.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html#pandas-series-lt):

```
df['diff'] = df['ema'] - df['close']
df['worth'] = df['diff'].lt(0)
```

```
        close           ema        diff  worth
194  40127.34  39330.573417 -796.766583   True
195  40104.08  40326.088399  222.008399  False
196  40039.18  40320.407044  281.227044  False
197  39869.20  40311.472251  442.272251  False
198  39958.01  40304.472999  346.462999  False
```

---

DataFrame and imports used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'close': {194: 40127.34, 195: 40104.08, 196: 40039.18, 197: 39869.2,
              198: 39958.01},
    'ema': {194: 39330.573417, 195: 40326.088399, 196: 40320.407044,
            197: 40311.472251, 198: 40304.472999}
})
```

Comment: Nice but pretty sure the `np.where` isn’t needed? Can you not just use `lt`?

Comment: It depends. Overhead of named `Series` and aligning is often slower than with the `array` from `np.where` but I've included it as an option. Thank you!

Comment: I am testing it with `np.where` and the false value seems to be correct. waiting for true value. Also what was wrong in my approach can you please explain as to what was happening with my code

Comment: I don't know since I don't have enough rows to run. I don't know that the indexes align correctly with range. I also am getting a set on copy of a slice warning which is known to have unexpected behaviours. I would assume you are setting to a copy of a slice so the effects are not taking affect in the frame. But without a MRE I can't say more.

Comment: Thanks @HenryEcker and tomjn for all the help. The code works!